# saving state on compound view widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

## Question

How do you save view widget instance state when, by using XML-defined widget layouts, components of the individual widget instances all have the same ID?

## Example

Take, for example, the `NumberPicker` widget that's used in the `TimePicker` widget (note that `NumberPicker` is not exposed to the SDK). This is a simple widget with three components which are inflated from `number_picker.xml`: one increment button, one decrement button, and one `EditText` where you can directly enter a number. In order for the code to interact with these widgets, they all have IDs (`R.id.increment`, `R.id.decrement` and `R.id.timepicker_input` respectively).

Let's say you have three `NumberPicker`s in an XML layout and you give them distinct IDs (eg. `R.id.hour`, `R.id.minute`).¹ This layout is then inflated to the content view of an activity. We decide to change the activity's orientation, so `Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` helpfully saves our view state for each view that has an ID (this is the default behavior).

Unfortunately, the three `NumberPicker`s have `EditText`s that all share the same ID — `R.id.timepicker_input`. Thus, when the activity is restored, the one furthest down in the view hierarchy is the one whose state seems to be preserved for all three of them. Additionally, the focus goes to the first `NumberPicker` when restored regardless of which one had focus when saved.

`TimePicker` gets around this problem by preserving the state itself, separately. Unfortunately, this won't preserve the cursor position or the focused view without a lot more work. I'm not sure how it preserves that state if it does at all (and quickly playing with a time input dialog seems to indicate that it can somehow).

Please see the sample code to demonstrate this issue:
https://github.com/xxv/AndroidNumberPickerBug

---

¹ In the view hierarchy, this sets the ID of the `LinearLayout` that `NumberPicker` extends to your IDs.

Comment: kindly smooth down the question . its a pain reading this now

Comment: @Javanator: I rewrote it, hopefully more clearly this time. Note to self: do not write complex SA questions at 4AM.

Comment: It looks like there's a bug in Android due to this issue. The TimePicker widget doesn't handle this properly: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5483

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I stumbled across the same issue when trying to create my own compound view. From looking at the Android source code I believe the correct way to implement compound views is for the compound view itself to take on the responsibility of saving and restoring the instance state of its children and to prevent the calls to save and restore instance state from being passed onto the child views. This works around the issue of the IDs of child views not being unique when you have more then one instance of the same compound view in an activity.

This might sound complicated but it is really quite easy and the APIs actually make provision for this exact scenario. I've written a blog post [here](http://charlesharley.com/2012/programming/views-saving-instance-state-in-android) on how this is done but essentially in your compound view you need to implement the following 4 methods, customising onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() to meet your specific requirements.

```
@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    return new SavedState(superState, numberPicker1.getValue(), numberPicker2.getValue(), numberPicker3.getValue());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());

    numberPicker1.setValue(savedState.getNumber1());
    numberPicker2.setValue(savedState.getNumber2());
    numberPicker3.setValue(savedState.getNumber3());
}

@Override
protected void dispatchSaveInstanceState(SparseArray container) {
    // As we save our own instance state, ensure our children don't save 
    // and restore their state as well.
    super.dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(container);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchRestoreInstanceState(SparseArray container) {
    /** See comment in {@link #dispatchSaveInstanceState(android.util.SparseArray)} */
    super.dispatchThawSelfOnly(container);
}
```

Regarding the problem with NumberPicker/TimePicker, as mentioned in another comment there appears to be a bug with NumberPicker and TimePicker. To fix it you could override both and implement the solution I've described.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I tried it and it works as advertised. Thank you!

Comment: It's worth to read @Charles Harley's [post about this issue in more details](http://www.charlesharley.com/2012/programming/views-saving-instance-state-in-android/), it is very well explained!

Comment: I have implemented this in my custom view, but onRestoreInstanceState is never called.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the exact same problem with a compound view
with three NumberPickers. I found a solution on another site
that involved reassigning the Id of the timepicker_input to
a unique random Id. This works but is complicated because once
a new Id is chosen, that Id must persist across configuration
changes so extra code is required to do that.

For my application, and probably in 99% of others, a much
simpler approach (hack) works. I realized that the namespace for
Ids has room for 65536 unique identifiers (0x7f090000 to
0x7f09ffff), but my application is only using 20 or so,
and they are allocated monotonically increasing from the
beginning. Furthermore, the NumberPicker widget itself
has a unique identfier within the tree (for example as in
the original post, R.id.hour, R.id.minute and R.id.second).
My solution is to reassign the Id of the EditText widget
to the Id of the NumberPicker widget plus an offset.

This is a one line change to the NumberPicker code. Simply
add:

```
mText.setId(getId() + 1000);
```

After the following line in NumberPicker.java:

```
mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timepicker_input);
```

The offset of course can be adjusted based on application requirements.

I imagine the same approach will work for other compound widgets.

For the above example, this approach allows the state of the
individual EditText widgets to be saved and restored, and the
focused view as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the game, but I wanted to give my input.

You can use the `android:tag` to group each `View`. Thus, you can 'reload' each state.

From the [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atag) website:

> android:tag
>
> Supply a tag for this view containing a String, to be retrieved later
>   with View.getTag() or searched for with View.findViewWithTag().

Answer (score 0):

I have a compound Widget with a state description consisting of a single integer `mValue`

Now override the following two methods like so:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchSaveInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    if(getId() != NO_ID) {
        Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
        p.writeInt(mValue);
        p.setDataPosition(0);
        container.put(getId(), new MyParcelable(p));
    }
}

@Override
protected void dispatchRestoreInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    if(getId() != NO_ID) {
        Parcelable p = container.get(getId());
        if(p != null && p instanceof MyParcelable) {
            MyParcelable mp = (MyParcelable) p;
            updateAllValues(mp.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

In `dispatchSaveInstanceState()`, you're serializing your state. More complex states will require more complex storage structures.

Make sure to `setDataPosition()` correctly.

I'm only saving the state if the widget has an id assigned which I'm using as the parcel's tag

In `dispatchRestoreInstanceState()`, you're unpacking your parcel.

I'm only performing the unpack if the widget has an id assigned and the container contains a parcel with a tag matching this id.

The `Parcelable` must also be of the proper class.

Unpacking will be more complicated for more complex widgets.

The last component needed is a `Parcelable` subclass like the following:

```
static class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {

    private int mValue;

    private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
        mValue = in.readInt();
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mValue);
    }

    int getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {

            public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new MyParcelable(source);
            }

            public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
                return new MyParcelable[size];
            }
    };

}
```

Using this framework is much easier than manipulating fragments and managing configuration

Answer (score -5):

Quite simple: You don't. Just go and disable the orientation change crap in your manifest file. The view state save mechanism is inherently flawed, they simply didn't think this through.

If you want to keep your state, you cannot reuse an id within a single activity. Which essentially means that you cannot use a single layout more than once, which makes more complex Widgets like TimePicker basically impossible to do properly.

You can make children keep their state by overriding `dispatchSaveInstanceState` and hacking it in, but I didn't find a way to keep focus as well, besides managing that yourself as well.

I think they could fix this by making state scope without breaking the API, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: I like your idea about making state scoped. It doesn't seem too challenging to add and I admit, I had assumed it would be there in the first place when I started playing with reusable widgets.

Comment: As an additional note: I haven't really worked with it yet, but chances are that the new Fragment API will fix problems like this. If every fragment keeps track of it's own state (like Activities do now) you could simply realize widgets as Fragments and reuse them at will. And best thing is, you can use the API in 2.x as well. I really, really do hope that it works like this, otherwise I'll lose my faith in Android.

Comment: That still doesn't address cases where you want to have two Widgets in the same "form" (for example, if you are using two date pickers in what would be the same Fragment). From what I understand, Fragments are intended to be a functional collection of widgets, usually for one complete set of interactions. If that's the case, I don't think using the Fragment API for what is essentially a widget would be a wise decision.

Comment: This problem is annoying me a lot right now. I have multiple instances of a compound double-Spinner on a form, and the system default which doesn't seem to be prevented, is to save the state of one pair of spinners and restore it to all.

Comment: The view stave state mechanism and rotation works fine, you just don't understand it. In a compound view you probably want to use dispatchThawSelfOnly in dispatchRestoreInstanceState -- this means the compound layout is in control of the all saving/restoring of state.

Comment: Yeah. I mentioned that. And no, I don't want to do that.